# How to push the coordinates of a first vertice of a polygon created with drawing manager and make them the last (closing) ones?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, polygons

Any advice on how to adjust this piece of code, so that it pushes the coordinates of a first vertice of a polygon (sort of repeats it) in the end to make it ready for kml files?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + ',' + polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ',0' + ";";
        }
        polygonArray.push(polygon);
        });
```

It's relatively easy to push the coordinates of a first vertice and make them display after every iteration of the loop but I wanted them to be added once and after the last unique vertice.

Now I am getting this:
17.38037109375,52.60971939156647,0;
17.314453125,51.89683388301249,0;
18.731689453125,52.456009392640766,0;

and would like to get this:
**17.38037109375,52.60971939156647,0;**
17.314453125,51.89683388301249,0;
18.731689453125,52.456009392640766,0;
**17.38037109375,52.60971939156647,0;**

I would appreciate a liitle help on that.
 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the first coordinate to the end of the string in the "info" div, just add it to the end:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lng() + ',' + polygon.getPath().getAt(i).lat() + ',0' + ";";
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(0).lng() + ',' + polygon.getPath().getAt(0).lat() + ',0' + ";";
  polygonArray.push(polygon);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip. I swear I tried it but obviously must've had some sort of mistake in the code. Damn... :)